# Who offers Conjunction Data Messages (CDM)

Tags: debris, ssa

I know space-track and LeoLabs offers Conjunction Data Messages.  Are there other commercial or open-source offerings?  How accurate are CDMs if you only used TLEs which do not include covariance.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you had two questions:

1. where to get CDMs, a further source is:

- https://www.eusst.eu/services/

3. CDMs from TLEs:

- basically useless, although it has been done by well-known satellite operations till some years ago.
- Problem is not only the missing covariance but also high uncertainties of the TLE generated state vector. TLEs are simple not exact enough for CA purposes. (e.g. from ESA SDO: ["Before 2010, the data ex-
  change was limited to the provision of low accuracy Two-
  line Elements (TLE) data, which come without information
  on accuracy. The estimated TLE accuracy is several 100 m
  up to several km (1-sigma)." Chapter 2.3](https://cddis.nasa.gov/lw21/docs/2018/papers/SessionSD3_Funke_paper.pdf) )